# Java and MySQL memory configuration issue with Activiti APS

Tags: java, mysql, activiti, jvm-arguments

We are using Tomcat based Activiti APS in production with MySQL database that have 36 Core CPU and 92 GB RAM.We have also increase the MySQL client-connection to 300(and set mysql connection-pool size 300 also in Activiti settings).

And RAM distribution is as follows:

1. 40 GB for JVM
2. 32 GB for MySQL inno_db_buffer_pool size

We have set the following JVM parameters:

```
JAVA_OPTS="-Xms6144m -Xmx40960m -XX:MetaspaceSize=512m -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=2048m -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=200 -XX:+UseParallelGC -XX:+UseParallelOldGC -XX:ErrorFile=/var/log/jvm.log"
```

But after 16-18 hours, the below red highlighted heap memory increased to 99% and MySQL throws "Too many connection" error.

[image]
Please suggest anyone, what is wrong in this configuration?

These are the following MySQL details:

[image]
Thanks

Comment: Where do you see that 99% the heap memory is used? In the line you highlighted in red it says "10%" at the end in the "Used" column. "Too many connections" to MySQL sounds like you might have a resource leak in your application (using database connections but not closing them).

Comment: Activiti holds a connection to DB open during task execution. It may appear if you have a lot of long-running tasks. Could you provide more details on running tasks?

Comment: I mean, after 16-18 hours the red highlighted goes to 99%.

Comment: There are 19043 active tasks now in Activiti.

Comment: Please post from MySQL login as root and from MySQL Command Prompt TEXT results of A) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE '%thread%'; and B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE '%thread%'; and C) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; for analysis.

Comment: Please see attached image in the last section in question.

Comment: Also, please check if there are any task delegate implementations that are opening any connections (to detect, ofcouse, any connection leak)

Comment: @RahiAkela With 19043 active tasks, does your software ever use TaskService.complete as listed in this URL  -  https://www.activiti.org/userguide/#bpmnFirstExampleEndingProcess - ?  It appears something is left hanging that should have been terminated.  Please lead your comment with atsign my name if the comment is for me.  We do not know the version of MySQL or Activiti that you are using, please post this information. Thanks